# Find user location with mapbox and Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

To be honest I still have some difficulty to understand how to call the native IOS api with Nativescript. I've read some brief tutorials on how to build a plugin for Nativescript, but I guess a bit of knowledge with Objective-C or Android is required.
I would like to center the map to the user location using the EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-mapbox plugin and because I can't find any method that return the user coordinates, I'm trying to mimic the structure of this plugin to add a new method:

on mapbox.d.ts

```
export function findUserPosition(): Promise<any>;
```

on mapbox.ios.js

```
mapbox.findUserPosition = function(){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     try {
       console.log('trying to get the user location.....')
       mapbox.mapView.userLocation = MGLUserLocation.location;
       console.dir(mapbox.mapView.userLocation)
       resolve();
     } catch (ex) {
       console.log("Error in mapbox.findUserLocation: " + ex);
       reject(ex);
     }
  });
};
```

on map-view-model.js

```
 DemoAppModel.prototype.findUserPosition = function(){
   mapbox.findUserPosition().then(function(result){
     console.log(result)
   },function(error){
     console.log(error)
   })
 };
```

Comment: You could use `nativescript-geolocation` - https://docs.nativescript.org/hardware/location plugin or `nativescript-google-maps-sdk` - https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk in case you want to get user location in your application.

Comment: @NikolayTsonev The nativescript-geolocation plugin it's a good idea, I'll give it a try. Thx